# jQuery Mobile- How to format strings in a split list item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to align 3 different String in a split list item (note that the other item is a delete popup)

The Ul is dynamic `$('#bonusProductList').append(st1+st2+st3);`

So no matter what size of string s1,s2 or s3, I want it to display evenly.

S11=========S222222222222=S333333

S1==========S222==========S3333

(instead of =, space)

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a 3 column grid within each LI:

> **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qcrU4/1/)**

I am using fake data from an array and then dynamically creating the list items with the 3 strings placed within a jQM 3 column grid:

```
var thedata = [
    ['S11', 'S222222222222', 'S333333' ],
    ['S1', 'S2222222', 'S33333333'],
    ['S11111', 'S22222222222', 'S3333'],
    ['S1111111', 'S2', 'S3333333333']
];

$("#page1").on("pageinit", function(){     
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {        
        var li = $('<li><a href="#"><div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="overflowtext">' + thedata[i][0] +'</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="overflowtext">' + thedata[i][2] +'</div></div><div class="ui-block-c"><div class="overflowtext">' + thedata[i][3] +'</div></div></div></a><a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"></a></li>');   
        $('#bonusProductList').append(li);     
    }            
    $('#bonusProductList').listview('refresh');    
});
```

UPDATE: added CSS to truncate text when screen becomes narrow:

```
.overflowtext {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

For word wrap instead of truncation, the CSS becomes:

```
.overflowtext {
    padding: 4px;
    white-space: normal;    
}
```

If you want word wrap with text that has no spaces or you want to break long words:

```
.overflowtext {
    padding: 4px;
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
}
```

> word-wrap **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qcrU4/3/)**, or break words **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qcrU4/5/)**

jQM grid docs can be found here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/

Comment: Text needs to be truncated, they will overlap.

Comment: Thanks @Omar, I updated the fiddle and the answer to add text truncation.

Comment: Thanks! Works for big layouts, but for example 320x480 string 3 is on top of string 2. If strings are too big I want them to go to next line. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: If your text has spaces, this will give you wrapping: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qcrU4/3/. If you have long text with no spaces, truncation is better...

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve over-writing strings(s1+s2). When I make the jsfiddle page smaller you can see the issue.

Comment: Can you give an example that will work for 320X480 as well? Thanks!